# x509certificate certpath validation

Tags: java, security, tomcat, x509certificate, pki

Our use-case requires validating certificate revocation via OCSP on a PKIX set-up.  My starting point was the code at this related question: [OCSP Revocation on client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161504/ocsp-revocation-on-client-certificate)

I'm doing it manually at the application level since tomcat doesn't support it.  However, I'm having some trouble building the certPath and I think I'm missing some fundamental understanding.

First I try to create the certPath for the incoming client x509Certificate.

KeyStore store is initialized correctly and contains only the root certificates that match the client x509Certificate.

EDIT: I got the same result after adding the intermediate certificates as well.

```
X509CertSelector certSelector = new X509CertSelector();
certSelector.setSubject(x509certificate.getSubjectX500Principal());
PKIXParameters params = new PKIXBuilderParameters(store,certSelector);
CertPathBuilder cpb = CertPathBuilder.getInstance(CertPathBuilder.getDefaultType());
CertPath certPath = cpb.build(params).getCertPath();
```

However, I get an error at run-time:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

What could be missing?

Answer (score 3):

As you have it, I'm not sure how the CPB would find the subject certificate (x509certificate) to build a path to, unless it's in your keystore, which it typically wouldn't be. Simply providing the subject name isn't enough to build a validated path; the discovery & validation algorithm needs the full subject certificate. See what happens if you replace

```
certSelector.setSubject(x509certificate.getSubjectX500Principal());
```

with

```
certSelector.setCertificate(x509certificate);
```

Answer (score 2):

You indicate that you added intermediates certificates. Since you did not update your code snippet I wondered how added these certificates? You should add these certificates as a `CertStore`

```
X509CertSelector certSelector = new X509CertSelector();
certSelector.setSubject(x509certificate.getSubjectX500Principal());
PKIXParameters params = new PKIXBuilderParameters(store,certSelector);
CertStore cstore = CertStore.getInstance("Collection", new CollectionCertStoreParameters(Arrays.asList(icert1, icert2 /*, other certs... */)));
params.addCertStore(cstore);
CertPathBuilder cpb = CertPathBuilder.getInstance(CertPathBuilder.getDefaultType());
CertPath certPath = cpb.build(params).getCertPath();
```

Comment: yes, that's how I did it.  However, I found another solution to my original question, that didn't involve these api gymnastics.